# como eu poderia checar se a pessoa clicou em um button

Tags: php

```
<button class="btt"><a href="carrinho.php?prod=<?= $skins['id_skin']?>">Comprar</a></button>
```

bom eu queria checar se a pessoa realmente clicou no botão e se o get = carrinho.

Comment: O `<a>` não pode estar dentro de um `<button>`.

Comment: como seria então? Eu queria checar se a pessoal reamente clicou no button.

Comment: se ele clicou no button eu iria fazer um if para ele pegar o id, e checar se existe uma sessão item.

Comment: não está, eu criei apenas o button mesmo.

Comment: @sam e como eu faria a checagem dos get? manda uma resposta para q eu possa votar nela como positivo bro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> O elemento `<a>` não pode ser descendente do elemento `<button>`.

Você pode incluir mais um parâmetro da URL com um nome de valor `carrinho`:

```
carrinho.php?prod=<?=$skins['id_skin']?>&clique=carrinho
```

No PHP você verifica se o parâmetro `clique` é igual a `carrinho`:

```
$prod = $_GET['prod'];
$clique = $_GET['clique'];

// $clique igual a "carrinho" e $prod não é vazio
if($clique == "carrinho" && !empty($prod)){
   // fazer algo
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cr5aqznd/ mano vc pode me dizer se eu tive a logica certa?

Comment: Criei um if pra verificar se não existe a sessão itens (que é um array) é pq não tem produto, se não ele vai somar ( pq já tem produto adicionado).

Comment: Parece ok, mas é bom sempre testar.